# Meteor Timed variable resets

Tags: meteor, reset, clock, var, timed

I'm making a game with meteor and I want certain variables to reset at the end of everyday.. DO you know how I would go about doing that?
Like at the end of everyday the amount of turns goes back to ten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [momentjs](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment) package for this.

First run.

```
meteor add momentjs:moment
```

Now you can do the follow

```
var day = moment().endOf('day').fromNow(),
    day1 = moment().startOf('day').fromNow();
    console.log("the days ends in " + day)
    console.log("the days starts " + day1)
     if(day === "in 0 hours"){
        alert("The day is over")
        Session.set("dayOver",true)
      }

    if(day1 === "in 24 hours ago"){
        alert("The day is over")
        Session.set("dayOver",true)
     }
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ethana/FLhpq/534/)

NOTE: There should be another way, also this take the client time, never trust on the client time, if you want to take the safe time from the server try the [mizzao/meteor-timesync](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync) package

Try it

```
meteor add mizzao:time sync
```

and you can do things like.

```
var serverTime = TimeSync.serverTime().

serverTime.format(). //for example
```

Comment: Wait. so for the second option would it be like if serverTime = 0 then execute what I want?

Comment: The second option its just an idea, total diferent the first options will work great

Comment: Am I able to just stick my commands under the Session.set("dayOver",true)?

Comment: Yes don't forget also to declare it as a `Session.setDefault('dayOver',false)`

Comment: How would I display the time with this app? I have                                     var now = moment();
moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); and then         Server time: {{now}} but it doesn;t seem to work and also will this work even if user is disconnected?

Comment: You should return that value in a template helper Template.example.helpers({time:function(){return now}}) sorry about bad code format im on the iphone